# Get-values from a html form in a for/do loop

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a problem with get-value() method in progress4GL.
I am trying to get all values from html form.

My Progress4GL Code looks like:

```
for each tt:
  do k = 1 to integer(h-timeframe):   
        h-from  [k]  = get-value(string(day(tt.date)) + "#" + string(tt.fnr) + "#" + string(tt.pnr) + "_von"  + string(k)).
        h-to    [k]  = get-value(string(day(tt.date)) + "#" + string(tt.fnr) + "#" + string(tt.pnr) + "_bis"  + string(k)).
        h-code  [k]  = get-value(string(day(tt.date)) + "#" + string(tt.fnr) + "#" + string(tt.pnr) + "_code" + string(k)).
  end.    
end.
```

- h-timeframe is parameter and could be max. 10. (1-10)
- tt is a temp-table and represents a week(fix 7 days)

It works perfectly till 9.Parameter. If I choose the 10 (which is max) then I get some performance Problem using **get-value()** Function.

Example when h-timeframe = 10: [image]

as you can see from one get-value to another It takes really long time.( h-timeframe = 10 )

Example when h-timeframe = 9: [image]

and here way much faster than other.

Can anyone explain why ? It is really strange and I have no Idea.

p.s: I have this problem just at 10. 0-9 It works perfectly

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario where iterating to 10 instead of 9 would impact performance for the first 9 iterations... Could there be something else happening in the system?

Comment: to be honest I have no Idea. It works on my server perfectly but on another one really really slow. Same source code.

Comment: Run the two versions on the /same/ server. You may want to look at the source code of get-value in web/method/cgiutils.i - see https://github.com/consultingwerk/ADE-Sourcecode/blob/41f3bf2e90cea6537a4717a6b277a9cfcd8dd36e/src/web/method/cgiutils.i#L536

Comment: Also consider get-field or get-cookie depending on what kind of transport you use... I think get-value tries both... Storing temp-table values in a cookie sounds strange to me. I should perhaps be posted as a form instead?

Comment: Something has changed in the `ammk99800004h.html` program between the 2 runs - notice the line numbers differ in the screenshots. The 'slow' one runs line 15475; the 'fast' on runs line 15492. If you run the same code do you see the speed differences?

Comment: @nwahmaet Thank you for your comment. I took screenshots not at the same time .

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference is probably something external to your code snippet but, for performance, I would write it more like this:

```
define variable d as integer   no-undo.
define variable n as integer   no-undo.
define variable s as character no-undo.

for each tt:

  // avoid recalculating and invoking functions N times per TT record

  assign
    d = day( tt.date )
    n = integer( h-timeframe )
    s = substitute( "&1#&2#&3_&&1&&2", d, tt.fnr, tt.pnr )
  .

  do k = 1 to n:

    // consolidate multiple repeated operations, eliminate STRING() calls

    assign
      h-from [k] = get-value( substitute( s, "von",  k ))
      h-to   [k] = get-value( substitute( s, "bis",  k ))  
      h-code [k] = get-value( substitute( s, "code", k ))  
    .

  end.    
end.
```

Comment: Thank you Tom.  Where did you use "tt.pnr" in substitute function ?

Comment: Looks like I copied it a bit too fast and skimmed over that bit.  I have updated the code.

Comment: While a lot nicer to read, improving the performance on something that takes 0ms (in the 9 case log) would not be my first priority.

Comment: It wouldn't be my first priority either. Nicer to read is definitely worth more in this case. The general habit of writing nicer to read code that also performs better when circumstances change, like maybe an enhancement to the web code that allows K to go to 100, or 1000, is a good habit to form. It would not, however, be good to prematurely optimize by writing LESS readable code for no good reason.